# Timestamps in laravel is not working well

Tags: laravel-5, timestamp

What happen to my `created_at` and `updated_at` fields?  Im using **laravel5.1**. I have this on my table:

=====================================
Name               type               default
created_at   |   timestamp  |  0000-00-00 00:00:00 
updated_at  |   timestamp  |  0000-00-00 00:00:00

**Migration is this:**

```
$table->increments('id')->unsigned();
$table->timestamps();
```

**Result**
 `The red is my actual date, the first green is the created_at and the second green is the updated_at`

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the model please?

Comment: Hm this is just a `pivot table`

Comment: Just a check; if your MySql locale is correctly set to your current one. Ideally if it's running on a local machine it should show the right time. Is it the same for all the tables or specific to this pivot table?

Comment: Oh! It is working before. but, all of my table now, is not working well with timestamps

Comment: Check the `timezone` in `config/app.php`, it may be using `UTC`

Comment: Yes, it is using `UTC`

Comment: I got it men :)